# Why is my entered table name is different from actual table name when I use delete in MySQL

Tags: mysql

See the picture.There is `orders` table in example, but havn't `archive_orders` in example.
[image]

Comment: What is your table engine? Can you  post results for `show create table example.orders`?

Comment: Check does the trigger BEFORE/AFTER DELETE exists on your table.

Comment: It‘s InnoDB. And it actually have a BEFORE DELETE TRIGGER.It solved.